# removing left/right padding on col-md-6 Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site utilizing Bootstrap but I want to override the left and right padding on just the columns col-md-6 (set them to 0px). Not sure how to do it, my current set up is ...

css

```
.fix-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.fix-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

and applying it to

```
<div id="main" class="row fix-gutters">

    .... <div class="col-md-6"> ... etc.
```

but that col-md-6 sometimes gets replaced (Wordpress loop) with a col-md-12 div and I don't want .fix-gutters to apply if that's the case.

NOTE: i need the override to happen on the same level as the col-md-6 command. example

```
<div class="col-md-6 overide-class">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will target them for you: (will only make the change to elements inside the `main` div)

`#main > .col-md-6{padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;}`

Answer (score 6):

*If* you want to add another class, just add a class called `no-padding`.

Then, in your CSS, add:

```
.no-padding {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: problem is that that row line gets applied to whatever is inside. Sometimes its a col-md-12 and sometimes its a col-md6. When it's col-md-6 I want its right/left padding removed

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add an new class to what you are allready but specify it for `col-md-6`

See example Snippet at FullPage.

```css
.fix-gutters > [class*="col-"],
.fix-gutters-six > [class*="col-md-6"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container text-center">
  <h2>
  Removed Padding only from Medium 6 Columns
  </h2>
  <div class="row fix-gutters-six">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Removed Padding on 6 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Removed Padding on 6 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Default 12 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>
    Default Columns
  </h2>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Default 6 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Default 6 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Default 12 Columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row fix-gutters">
    <h2>
    Removed Padding from All Columns
  </h2>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Removed Padding from all Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="alert alert-info">
        Removed Padding from all Columns
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Removed Padding from all Columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap 4.x.x you can achieve this by applying `pl-0` to the left column and `pr-0` to the right column. See [Spacing - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) for more information.